# Font Awesome background + Size

Tags: font-awesome

A long time ago I made this with font awesome: [image: fontawesome icon]

For the life of me, I can't remember how I done it. I tried to replicate it using this:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa fa-home fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

I used this resource for the above code: [Stacked Icons, Twitter](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)

The problem with this is that the house is too big, and the background isn't the same as the one I made ages ago (think #fff). On the fontawesome website it appears to have a light background, but then when implementing it into my site (background of the site is #1F1F1F), it seems to take the same background as the site.

Does anyone know how I was able to do this previously and now I'm struggling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem: too big**

You're using the `fa-lg` class. This makes it oversized. Remove this.

**Problem: wrong background**

Use the `fa-square` class (a solid rounded square, instead of outline like `fa-square-o`), and use CSS to make it light (with `color: lightgrey`).

(In the below example, I also darkened the background to better show the light background of the square).

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.light {
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x light"></i>
  <i class="fa fa fa-home fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked.

Comment: @AndreA I'm glad I helped!